# Can we use #define in JSON file

Tags: ios, json

I a `Constants.h` header file in my Xcode project.

Constants.h

```
#ifndef JSONExperiments_Constants_h
#define JSONExperiments_Constants_h

enum controllers
{

    COURSE_LIST_CONTROLLER = 0,
    TIMELINE_CONTROLLER,
    TIMESCALE_CONTROLLER,
    DEVICE_MANAGER,
    MAIN_TIMELINE_VIEW_CONTROLLER,
};

enum relationship
{

    MOVE_UP = 1,
    MOVE_DOWN,
    MOVE_LEFT,
    MOVE_RIGHT,
};

#endif
```

and I have `Relationship.json` file in my project.

```
[

    {
        "COURSE_LIST_CONTROLLER":
        {
            "relatives": ["TIMELINE_CONTROLLER"],
            "relationships":
            {
                "TIMELINE_CONTROLLER": ["MOVE_UP","MOVE_DOWN"]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

While parsing the JSON file I'm getting the value of "COURSE_LIST_CONTROLLER" as a string but I want it as enum value from the `Constants.h` file.

1. Is there any way to use `Constants.h` file inside the `Relationship.json` file.
2. Or can I convert this string value to equivalent enum value.

Comment: Things don't work that way, you either need to use the numeric value in your JSON file (instead of the string), or parse the string yourself.  These enums get made at compile time, but your JSON won' tbe read until runtime.  It doesn't get compiled.

Comment: thank you borrrden, if i choose xml for the same feature there is any possible to achieve.

Comment: No, for the same reason.  This stuff is not code, it is data.